# CKAN API search query returns zero results

Tags: api, search, solr, ckan

I'm using CKAN portal with API version "ckan_version": "2.2b"

When I use API to search for data modified after certain date I get 0 results.

When I search for all data packages I can see that `metadata_modified` property exist and should be returned by `example1` query.

`example1`:

```
/api/action/package_search?q=metadata_modified:[2016-01-04T21:15:00Z%20TO%20*]
```

I get:

```
"success": true, "result": {"count": 0, "sort": "score desc, popularity desc, name asc", "facets": {}, "results": [], "search_facets": {}}}
```

With this `example2` query:

```
/api/action/package_search?q=
```

I get:

```
"success": true, "result": {"count": 187, "sort": "score desc, popularity desc, ...
```

with `metadata_modified` properties that should be returned with `example1` query.

I think that this issue is related to https://github.com/datagovuk/dgu-vagrant-puppet/issues/27 . Any suggestions on SOLR setup for Drupal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are using the ckanext-dgu extension, which until recently escaped SOLR control characters in searches.

You can either get rid of the escaping, as we've done: https://github.com/datagovuk/ckanext-dgu/pull/322

Or I believe you can specify another parameter to avoid the escaping: `escape_q=False`

I don't see any link of your problem to Drupal or that issue you mention.